# Expo React Native BareWorkflow and Firebase Error

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, expo

I'm having problems using expo react native bare workflow (I'm not using expo go) and firebase. The project does not compile, returning several errors.

Configuration steps:

(https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/#using-react-native-firebase):

- npx expo install expo-dev-client
- npx expo install @react-native-firebase/app

(https://rnfirebase.io/#managed-workflow)

- Download the file "google-services.json" and insert it in "/android/app/"

```
# /android/build.gradle

buildscript {
  dependencies {
    // ... other dependencies
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    // Add me --- /\
  }
}
```

```
# /android/app/build.gradle
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' // <- Add this line
```

```
# app.json
{
  "expo": {
    "android": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./google-services.json"
    },
    "ios": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./GoogleService-Info.plist"
    },
    "plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app"
    ]
  }
}
```

- npx expo prebuild
- npx expo run:android

And I get errors:

```
npx expo run:android
› Building app...
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.

> Configure project :app
 ??  Applying gradle plugin 'expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin' (expo-dev-launcher@2.2.1)

> Configure project :expo-application
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-constants
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-dev-client
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-dev-launcher
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-dev-menu
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-dev-menu-interface
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-file-system
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-font
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-json-utils
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-keep-awake
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-manifests
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

> Configure project :expo-modules-core
WARNING:Software Components will not be created automatically for Maven publishing from Android Gradle Plugin 8.0. To opt-in to the future behavior, set the Gradle property android.disableAutomaticComponentCreation=true in the `gradle.properties` file or use the new publishing DSL.

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\node_modules\expo-modules-autolinking\scripts\android\autolinking_implementation.gradle' line: 326

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':expo'.
> A problem occurred configuring project ':expo-modules-core'.
   > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
      > SDK location not found. Define a valid SDK location with an ANDROID_HOME environment variable or by setting the sdk.dir path in your project's local properties file at 'C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\android\local.properties'.
      > Could not get unknown property 'release' for SoftwareComponentInternal set of type org.gradle.api.internal.component.DefaultSoftwareComponentContainer.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':expo'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 25s
10 actionable tasks: 8 executed, 2 from cache
Error: C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\android\gradlew.bat exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:52:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1093:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at Object.spawnAsync [as default] (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:17:21)
    at spawnGradleAsync (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:72:46)
    at Object.assembleAsync (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\start\platforms\android\gradle.js:52:18)
    at runAndroidAsync (C:\Users\pc\Desktop\Nova pasta\test\node_modules\@expo\cli\build\src\run\android\runAndroidAsync.js:31:24)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

The solution I was looking for at that moment was to start the project with "npx expo start" choosing the "android" option. The project compiles normally.

To test, I install realtime:

- yarn add @react-native-firebase/database
- npx expo prebuild

```
# App.js
...
import database from '@react-native-firebase/database';

export default function App() {
  const reference = database().ref('/test/');
  console.log(reference)

  return (
...
...
```

And I get news errors:

```
Error: You attempted to use a firebase module that's not installed on your Android project by calling firebase.app().

Ensure you have:

1) imported the 'io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage' module in your 'MainApplication.java' file.

2) Added the 'new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage()' line inside of the RN 'getPackages()' method list.
...
...
```

In "MainApplication.java" I do:

```
# MainApplication.java
...
import io.invertase.firebase.app.ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage;
...
...
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
  ...
  packages.add(new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage());
  return packages;
}
```

When recompiling and running the project, the error persists.

Can you help me?